# Looking for advice on a Visual Studio/VS Code language for non-developer

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio

In short, I am looking to create a POC (proof of concept) for an interface I have designed for aggregating data from several different sources. Currently I am just using flat tables in SQL with no relationships (although there are fields that are in the data for that purpose) to store the data, which is being gathered by various means (mostly PowerShell scripts). I also want it to be modular enough so I can add hooks to REST calls to other sources. So, if I make a call to get data about a certain asset, I don't have to know where that data is at that level. The middleware will know where to find it and use the appropriate method to get it (SQL, REST, etc.).

I have been in IT for over 31 years, I have experience with SQL (and have been a professional DBA at one point), a few scripting languages, and wrote a similar app in C# at one point, but I was given a template interface from a profession developer and I just ran with that and changed it as I went.

I want a high level view with colors indicating general health of a location, and the ability to search the data for assets (this could be anything from a VM, BM server, ethernet switches, FC switches, connected SAN, hypervisors, vCenters, Nutanix clusters, etc.) to find their location, health and most importantly, their connections to other assets.

I know a little about everything, enough to be dangerous in most and some a master of. What direction should I go here? I know BASIC, PowerShell well enough to call myself an expert, but more than likely, just a hacker. I know the basic concepts of coding well enough (I was an adjunct at a CC 20+ years ago) to teach it to others. I want to use a language I will be able to hand over to a professional to maintain once we have a new DevOps member on the team.

EDIT: I wrote a very small program earlier this year using React. That was broken into the interface and the 'middleware' with two separate project. Java is not an intuitive language for me and I could go this direction again, but I am looking for possible alternatives.

Comment: What is POC? also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Your previous experience doesn't help the next person with the same question.

Comment: (Disclaimer: I am a Google dev on GCP) there are existing solutions for this such as [Google Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a 'non-developer' way of doing this unfortunately. If you really want to do this yourself, I'd suggest a C# API since you have some experience in that (even if it's minimal, it's still comfort), and luckily for you they just released minimal API's which should make your life much easier (https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2021/07/16/building-minimal-apis-in-net-6/).

In terms of actually displaying the data, if it's a really simple UI I'd just keep it simple and use JavaScript and HTML/CSS (ie no frameworks such as React). It's a POC, and if someone comes in and wants to move over to using a framework because there's more work to be done on it, it's not that hard to take your existing code and move it into something more modern. But if it's small, a framework would be over engineering this, especially if you need to learn it all.

For smaller projects like this, you can kind of learn the code you need for the project, without needing to truly learn to code. Get your components from a library like Bootstrap (it's basically premade elements like your dropdowns, progress bars etc, their documentation is pretty good), and keep it as simple as possible. Good luck!